# Как изменить видимость объекта в Delphi 7 через скрипт?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать скрипт, который при нажатии кнопки будет ставить значение параметра `Visible` на `False` у объекта, который будет указан в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Visible := false;
end;
```